# Weird node.js "object is not a function" error

Tags: node.js, typeerror

In my serverPlayer.js I have:

```
var player = function(startX, startY) {
var x = startX,
    y = startY,
    facingRight = true,
    id;

return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    id: id,
    facingRight: facingRight
    }
};

module.exports = player;
```

and in my gameServer I have:

```
var util = require('util'),
    player = require("./serverPlayer");

........

var newPlayer = new player(data.x, data.y); // that's where the error targets
```

When I start the server, everything goes fine. However, when I refresh the browser after 10 seconds, the server crush and gives me a "object is not a function" error.

Could anyone explain how this happens? Thanks so very much!

If you are interested, you can find the whole project at [github](https://github.com/zichuanwang/zichuangame)

Comment: You should not return id as "undefined". Initialize it

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've fixed this issue but it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Please look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

This, in `gameServer.js`, looks like the problem:

```
for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    player = players[i];
```

I don't see a `var player` anywhere or a `player` parameter on the functions in which this code is located. So it would assign to the top level `player` variable and overwrite the value you initialized it to.

Comment: have found myself running into such problems a few times, it's better to name required modules wisely to avoid conflicts, for instance `playerModule` would have been a better choice.